# Latex bibliography showing errors

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a Tex report in which I define some bibliography entries in my references.bib file like this:

```
@manual{darpadataset,
title = {DARPA Intrusion Detection Data Sets},
author = {Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Linclon Laboratory},
url = {https://www.ll.mit.edu/ideval/data/},
year = {1998-2000}
}

@online{RansomwareTracker,
title = {Ransomware Tracker Website},
url = {\url{https://ransomwaretracker.abuse.ch/tracker/}},
year = {2018}
}
@online{UNBCIC2017IDSDATASET,
title = {{UNBCIC 2017 IDS Dataset}},
url = {\url{http://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/ids-2017.html}},
year = {2017}
}
```

and the following is how I import the file:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
```

When I try to generate the PDF file using: PDFLatex and BibTex; the first execution shows no errors and the bibliography does not appear in my PDF file. However, during the second execution, I get the following errors:

```
! Use of \/ doesn't match its definition.
\do ... ~}{\mathchar \number \mathcode `#1\sb {\/}
                                              }\mathcode `#1=32768 \fi 
l.112 ...-intrusion-detection-evaluation-data-set}
                                              .
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

)
Runaway definition?
->\mathchar 96\sb {}\mathcode `\unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox 
\ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of `.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.30 \bibliography{references.bib}
```

Apparently it also suggests to me a solution but I don't get it very well. Could somebody help me fix it. Thanks.

The following is the code for my main file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\include{config}
\include{constants}



\begin{document}
\long\def\/*#1*/{}

\include{pages/abstract}
\include{pages/acknowledgements}


\include{chapters/chapter1/main}
\include{chapters/chapter2/main}
\include{chapters/chapter3/main}
\include{chapters/chapter4/main}
\include{chapters/chapter5/main}
\include{chapters/chapter6/main}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

In the config files I define the following packages:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}




\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell} % for more vertical space in cells
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{adjustbox}


\newcounter{inlineenum}
\renewcommand{\theinlineenum}{\alph{inlineenum}}
\newenvironment{inlineenum}
{\unskip\ignorespaces\setcounter{inlineenum}{0}%
\renewcommand{\item}{\refstepcounter{inlineenum} 
{\textit{\theinlineenum})~}}}
{\ignorespacesafterend}






\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

% subhead
\newcommand{\subhead}[1]{\vspace {0.03in}\noindent{\textbf{#1.}}}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textit{\alph*)}}

\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{url}%
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}%

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please, make a full example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\long\def\/*#1*/{}` is a really bad idea! Note your error message is about `\/`

Comment: Okay, it is working. Thanks for your quick reply @DavidCarlisle , it helped me fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

`\/` is a core latex comand for italic correction that is used internally for example in commands such as `\textit` but also lots of other places, and is likely to be explicitly inserted in some bibtex styles.

Doing a redefinition such as

```
\long\def\/*#1*/{}
```

will break all these uses.

In general you should use `\newcommand` rather than `\def` so that you do not accidentally redefine internal commands in this way.